# First React app not working properly in Safari

Tags: reactjs, input, safari

This is my first post on this site, so I'll do my best to follow local etiquette and expectations here. I just finished my first React app! I've been testing it with Firefox and Chrome during development, but just discovered that a couple features aren't working in Safari.

It uses local storage for the user's name and a Todo list component on the bottom right. In Firefox and Chrome these input fields work as expected, however in Safari the inputs don't register anything. I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Here is the code for the name input field:

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";

let Greeting = ({
  date
}) => {
  let [greeting, setGreeting] = useState([]);
  let [name, setName] = useState('');
  let [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');

  let saveData = (newName) => {
    localStorage.setItem("userName", newName)
  }

  let handleChange = (e) => {
    setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value)
    console.log(name)
  }

  let handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(userInput);
    saveData(userInput);
  }


  let handleDclick = () => {
    setUserInput(name);
    setName('');
    saveData('')
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    let getTheGreeting = () => {
      let hours = date.getHours()
      if (hours > 11 && hours < 17) {
        setGreeting(`Good afternoon, ${name}`)
      } else if (hours >= 17) {
        setGreeting(`Good evening, ${name}`)
      } else setGreeting(`Good Morning, ${name}`)
    }
    getTheGreeting();
    if (localStorage.getItem("userName")) {
      setName(localStorage.getItem("userName"));
    }
  }, [name, date])

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    h2 id = "greeting"
    onDoubleClick = {
      handleDclick
    } > {
      greeting
    } & nbsp; {
      name.length === 0 ?
        <
        span >
        <
        form onSubmit = {
          handleSubmit
        }
      id = "greeting-form" >
        <
        input value = {
          userInput
        }
      onChange = {
        handleChange
      }
      onSubmit = {
        handleSubmit
      }
      className = "greetinginput" / >
        <
        /form> <
        /span> : ''
    } <
    /h2> <
    /div> 
  )
}

export default Greeting;
```

here's a link to the app itself

https://robbpalmer.github.io/fakementum/